# Is there any Brackets 1.8 PPA with extract included?

Tags: apt, ppa, adobe-brackets

I added the following ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
```

then installed brackets using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

It worked, but the installed Brackets doesn't include Extract plugin which I need.

Does anyone know about a ppa which have extract included in brackets.

Thank You!

Comment: You might read [Extract discontinued] (https://www.quora.com/Since-Brackets-has-discontinued-Extract-what-is-the-best-option-for-converting-PSDs-to-HTML-CSS)

Comment: Thank You @heynnema, it's very sad that extract is discontinued. :(